# Class 'Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterFacade' not found in Laravel 5

Tags: twitter, laravel-5

I'm trying to send a tweet from my Laravel 5 app using thujohn/twitter, but I get this error:

> Class 'Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterFacade' not found

Here's my code

```
    return Twitter::postTweet(array('status' => 'Tweet sent using Laravel and the Twitter API!', 'format' => 'json'));
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This alias no longer works in Laravel 5:

```
'Twitter' => 'Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterFacade',
```

You must use

```
'Twitter' => 'Thujohn\Twitter\Facades\Twitter',
```

Instead in config/app.php